# does not allow user to vote for his own post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models **User**, **Post**, **Vote**

I need to doesn't allow user to vote for his own post. 
How I can make this in my models and test this in Rspec?

Post Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :main_text, :video, :photo, :tag

  validates :title,     presence: true, length:  {minimum: 1, maximum: 200}
  validates :main_text, presence: true, length:  {minimum: 1}

  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :votes

end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :bio

  has_many :posts
  has_many :votes

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: {minimum: 1, maximum: 120}
  validates :email, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 250}, uniqueness: true, 
                    format: {:with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i}


end
```

Vote model:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :user_id, :post_id, :units

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post

  validates :post_id, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}  #does not allow user to vote for the same post twice


end
```

My spec test for Vote:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Vote do

  it "does not allow user to vote for the same post twice" do 
    user = User.create(name: "Nik", email: "nik@google.com" )
    post = Post.create(title: "New Post", main_text: "Many, many, many...")
    vote1 = Vote.create(user_id: user.id, post_id: post.id)  
    vote1.errors.should be_empty    
    vote2 = Vote.create(user_id: user.id, post_id: post.id)        
    vote2.errors.should_not be_empty      
  end 

  it "does not allow user to vote for his own post" do
    user = User.create(name:"Nik", email:"a@a.ru")
    post = Post.create(user_id: user.id, title: "New Post", main_text: "Many, many, many...")
    vote1 = Vote.create(user_id: user.id, post_id: post.id)
    vote1.errors.should_not be_empty
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tested the following code so it could not work or even kill your cats but try with a custom validation with add an error if the vote's user is the same of the post's user.

Note I return if the user or the post are nil for obvius reasons.

```
# In your vote model
validate :users_cant_vote_their_posts

def users_cant_vote_their_posts
  return if user.nil? or post.nil?
  if user_id == post.user_id
    errors[:base] = "A user can't vote their posts"
  end
end
```

**EDIT**: Here a possible test, here I'm using FactoryGirl to generate votes. Again this code is not tested (sorry for the pun)

```
describe Vote do
  subject { vote }

  let!(:vote) { FactoryGirl.build(:vote) }

  it 'from factory should be valid' do
    should be_valid
  end

  context 'when user try to double vote' do
    before do
      # Create another vote from user to post
      FactoryGirl.create(:vote, :user => vote.user, :post => vote.post)
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  context 'when user try to vote his posts' do
    before do
      # Set the user whom voted to the post's owner
      vote.user = vote.post.user
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for idea... I go to spec)))

Comment: Can you help with spec test for this validation?

Comment: The spec I've seen in your question seems OK but I would suggest you 2 things, 1) Use factories (many use FactoryGirl), 2) User before blocks. Do you have problems with that test?

Comment: Oh and `return if user.nil? or post.nil?` is needed to avoid to avoid problems when Rails try to validate a Vote object without user or post (because you can't assume the presence validations on these fields are run before this custom validation).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ruby, but you should check whether the user signed in matches the user that made the post. And if it does, deny the request to vote.

Sorry if this is not helpful :)

Comment: I want to know how I can do this on Module level before I use devise gem. But thanks anyway